# Solution Explorer In VS 2013 Problim (No View Solution)

Tags: c#, vb.net

Helo

I have a problem in Solution where it does not appear in other projects Solution and I can not start a new project inside
The problem is that Solution name does not appear in the list, but it just shows that you saved the project, and circumvented it by adding a new folder before adding the project and then shows me the name of Solution , is it a Solution ?

Comment: What? I don't understand at all. Could you clarify?

Comment: what just happened? can you post a screenshot and explain?